# Moto 360 emulator for Android wear

Tags: java, android, android-layout, wear-os

How are developers emulating Moto 360 for Android wear?

- The resolution for the is Moto 320x290  - however, the default emulator emulates watches with resolution of 320x320 or 280x280 posing a bit of a problem.

Basically I am unsure how to design a watchface background for the Moto 360 - should it be 320x290 or should I design it to be 320x320 and the rest 30 pixes will just get chopped off?

Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to find an exact emulator with the little flat spot at the bottom but for the Moto 360 your background should be at 320x320 (XHDPI). The 320x320 round virtual devices will work pretty well for simulating the Moto 360. Just expect that the bottom will be cut off slightly.

For better explanation see this google blog entry here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/an-android-wear-design-story.html